# Vertical ScrollView of ListView without Height

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, scrollview, windows-10-universal

My UWP application has `ListView` with dynamic contents. I want to enable `ScrollView` when it's height reaches to the end of device height it runs(desktop/mobile). I don't want to set height/maximum height of `ListView`. Because it should display as it is.

I have tried like below. But it is not working. It works only if specify the height of `ListView`.

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions    >
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemListView" Margin="0,0,0,0"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="Auto"  >
            <!--ListView ItemTemplate to fill-->
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid  >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.RowSpan="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNum}" TextAlignment="Center"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XX}"  TextAlignment="Center"   />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YY}"  TextAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb_list_date" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ZZ}" TextAlignment="Center"  />

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AA}"  TextAlignment="Center" />

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"    Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BB}" TextAlignment="Center"/>                          </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
   </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Grid.RowDefinition` is set to `Auto` height. This lets the controls in the row to use any height they need. This causes the `ListView` to stretch beyond the boundaries of the page and because its height is actually the full height of the list, it does not scroll (but you can't see the overflow).

To fix this, change the `Grid.RowDefinition` `Height` to `*`. This will give the control all available space in the `Grid` but not more than that:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```